# Issues for taking screenshots for some urls using WebBrowser control (WinForms)

Tags: multithreading, winforms, iis, screenshot

My code (below) using a foreach loop for multiple urls and save screen shots of each url). This code works perfectly in my dev environment ( Visual studio 2010, Windows 7 64 bit).I can take screen shots of url and save it in a folder. But the same code I deployed in a server (Windows server 2003, IIS- 6.0), it is not saving screen shots for some url. I captured the logs and it says System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.System.Threading.Thread.JoinInternal().

Is it works with IIS 6.0 or any other settings has to do with the deployment server? It works perfectly in my local environment. Any help appreciated.

public void Capture(string url, string path)
    {
        _path = path;

```
    var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        using (var browser = new WebBrowser())
        {
            browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
            browser.AllowNavigation = true;
            browser.Navigate(url);
            browser.Width = 1600;
            browser.Height = 1600;
            browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            browser.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompleted;

            while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();
}
```

Comment: Is this winforms app? What IIS has to do with desktop app?

Comment: I suggest that you modify your error logging system so that for each exception it also logs the exception message, the InnerException (if exists) and the stack trace. The knowledge about the type of the exception only is rarely helpful.